# How to convert TSV to CSV using openoffice

Tags: openoffice.org

How do convert TSV file to CSV format using openoffice ?

Comment: "using openoffice" suggests superuser

Answer (score 2):

TSV = Tab separated ?

If so, just give it a .txt extension, open in the spreadsheet program (Calc) as CSV, the Wizard will ask you which is the field separator, choose TAB.
Afterwards, save it as a (true) CSV.

Comment: Ya I tried same. It again saves it as tab separated file with CSV extension

Comment: It works for me. Using Calc 3.1.1 here.
To save, I select "Save as", choose "Text CVS " , and (just to be sure) check the option "Edit filter settings". In that way you can verify-force, in the next dialog, that the the comma is used as separator for the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution that I found was find and replace, I used my emacs to replace "tab" with "," and it worked.

Comment: this would be error prone, in the case the fields have commas inside them