# Tab Delimites to CSV

Tags: csv

For a data mining project I need to convert 80 tab delimited files(100 MB each) to CSV files. Anybody is aware of some tools that can be handy in this case.

Comment: There are a lot of tools to do this. What Operating System are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using Windows 8.1. Or I can switch if there is any convenient tool available in other OS.

Comment: If you are not familiar with any scripting languages I would suggest Open Office Calc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549800/how-to-convert-tsv-to-csv-using-openoffice As long as the files do not have more than the limits?: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Miscellaneous/What%27s_the_maximum_number_of_rows_and_cells_for_a_spreadsheet_file%3F Or try to install python and use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0):

Download python: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Install it.

And run a script similar to the following.

Save the following as `convert_tsv_to_csv.py` Or anything ending in `.py`:

```
import csv
with open('C:\\path\to\file','r') as f:
    tab_file = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)

with open('C:\path\to\outfile.csv','w') as g:
    comma_file = csv.writer(g, dialect=csv.excel)

for row in tab_file:
    comma_file.writerow(row)
```

Change the paths and run it like: `python convert_tsv_to_csv.py`

The basic idea:
If the files are big, read them line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Learn your basic tools.

On any UNIX/Linux/OSX system, the following commands each should do the trick:

```
sed  -i    -e 's/\t/,/g' *.csv
perl -i -p -e 's/\t/,/g' *.csv
```

These perform the basic tab to comma substitution. They won't take care of things like quoting and escaping if your data contains columns with a tabular or comma, or chaning the file name for you! Note that the syntax of `sed` and `perl` are very similar... `-i` is inplace editing, `-e` is execute a command, `s///` is the syntax for regular expression substitutions. Etc.

Either way, your basic unix tools for this job are

1. extremely fast (the "stream editor" `sed` is well optimized, low-level C code)
2. handy (just some 10 keypresses!)
3. easy to use, once you've learned the basics (i.e. read the manual)